# Wrong risk ratio/relative risk calculation with escalc() metafor package for meta analysis

Tags: metafor

I have a quick (and I'm sorry if silly) question.

I am using the metafor package and this function:

```
data<-escalc(measure = "RR", ai=1, bi=0, ci=43, di=443, append=TRUE)
```

to calculate the relative risk.

While my manual calculations say its 11.30 (log(RR)=2.425), the escalc function throws a 8.40 (log(RR)=2.13).

I actually took this values from a research paper, and know for a fact that 11.30 is the correct result, but I have no clue on why this calculation gives 8.40.

Any help is very welcome

Answer (score 0, accepted):

When one of the cells is a 0, `escalc` applies the +1/2 continuity correction by default. If you don't want that, use `add=0`. See `help(escalc)`.

Comment: Thanks for the answer!! Even when applying 0.5 continuity to only0 or all, or when I specifically ask for no continuity correction, the result is still wrong ...

Comment: `escalc(measure = "RR", ai=1, bi=0, ci=43, di=443, add=0)` gives a value of 2.4250 for the log relative risk, exactly as you have in your manual calculations.